# org.omg.CORBA:MARSHAL & org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM error

Tags: java, corba, idl

Recently I experience problems during CORBA-comunication of a very old application I have to maintain.
Client and server part communicate via CORBA. On a particular function call from client on server I get 
folowing error:

```
Not successful call - original stacktrace 
java.lang.Exception
    at de.tc.app.lamo.bss.util.dialog.AbstractCallProxy.<init>(AbstractCallProxy.java:135)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.bss.util.dialog.CallProxy.<init>(CallProxy.java:68)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.bss.util.dialog.BasisCtl.initiateServerCall(BasisCtl.java:186)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.bss.util.dialog.BasisCtl.initiateServerCall(BasisCtl.java:198)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.bss.dialog.stz.STZCtl.funcLesen(STZCtl.java:106)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.bss.dialog.stz.STZView$1.actionPerformed(STZView.java:163)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:492)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:705)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:820)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1639)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2859)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2894)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2822)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6074)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4660)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1856)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:722)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1000)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:865)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:686)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4532)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:668)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:627)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:625)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:639)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:638)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception Serveraufruf: de.tc.app.lamo.awf.stub.Corba_St_STZAwf.lese
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.inprise.vbroker.orb.SE.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.inprise.vbroker.orb.DelegateImpl.handleReply(Unknown Source)
    at com.inprise.vbroker.orb.DelegateImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(ObjectImpl.java:457)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.awf.corba._STZAwfStub.lese(_STZAwfStub.java:272)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.awf.stub.Corba_St_STZAwf.lese(Corba_St_STZAwf.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.bss.util.dialog.AbstractCallProxy.call(AbstractCallProxy.java:145)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.bss.util.dialog.AbstractCallProxy.doCall(AbstractCallProxy.java:431)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.bss.util.dialog.AbstractCallProxy.run(AbstractCallProxy.java:346)
    at de.tc.app.lamo.bss.util.dialog.CallProxy.run(CallProxy.java:141)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The error is reproducible. During debugging I can see that data are loaded by the back end as usual and reached on to the client.
The client actually gets the response but is not able to process the data.

The same function call works for other data. There is only some particular data selection which doesn't come through.

I cannot detect any significant difference between those data. The idl-definitions weren't changed either.

Do you have any hints for me, where to look for the error cause?

Comment: Is that the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Hello John,
I added the entire stacktrace to my post. Any ideas now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to an advice of a friend the org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL is thrown, if server and client work with different lib-Versions.
I cannot explain how it could happen to my project, nevertheless this particular error disappeared on its own :-/

The actual Problem in my case was an org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM Exception, which was caused by the following line of code:

```
public static void write (final org.omg.CORBA.portable.OutputStream _output, final de.tc.app.lamo.comm.STZFlugereignis _vis_value) {
    ...
    _output.write_string((java.lang.String)_vis_value.flugNr);
    ...
    }
```

Where `_vis_value.flugNr` was null.

So a NullPointerException actually, but hidden by VisiBroker under CORBA-Exception together with the relevant stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same versions of all of the dependencies (jar files) on the client and the server.

Make sure the client and the server are running the same version of Java?

Comment: Hello John, 

Client and Server are both compiled with Java 6. Server is running on Java 7. Client is loaded per Java Web Start, so I don't have any influence on the Client JRE. I have to support Java 6 though. Till now it wasn't a problem. Some time ago the web interface, where I get the data to be shown in the client, was extended. But it shouldn't effect the CORBA communication. I don't know where to search anymore.